# Is this syntax incorrect?

Tags: css

this doesn't seem to be working, what is the issue? Thanks

```
.circle-1, circle-2,-circle-3 p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    color: #2970AE;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Open the javascript console in your browser, and try it. Tell us what happens. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: But at a glance, your selector does not look right to me. It looks like a selector is intended to work where (class=circle-1 OR element = circle-2 OR element = -circle-3) AND element=P.  That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, and I don't even know if "-circle-3" is legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If .circle-1,circle-2,circle-3 are classes then use:

```
.circle-1,.circle-2,.circle-3
```

If .circle-1, circle-2,-circle-3 are id's then use:

```
#circle-1,#circle-2,#circle-3
```

Except this, everything seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

You selector is addressing classes wrong. You didn't write a dot before the class names.

```
.circle-1, .circle-2, .circle-3 p
```

This selector will apply on every element that has the `circle-1` or `circle-2` classes, and on paragraphs inside elements that have the `circle-3` class.